# Can I use 10 V capacitor 2200 uF to change 6.3 V/4700 uF?

Tags: amplifier

Can 10 V capacitor 2200 uF to replace 6.3 V 4700 uF?

Comment: Generally: No. In any one application: depends. Tell more about requirements and candidate specifications - [in your question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Need more info. This is like asking "Can I replace bronze with steel?" Might be okay for a door knob, but not for a ship propeller.

Comment: It depends on the purpose of this particular capacitor.

Answer (score 2):

> *Can 10v capacitor 2200uf to replace 6.3v 4700uf*

The first two important parameters when replacing an electrolytic capacitor are: -

- The farad value should equal the one being changed
- The voltage rating of the replacement should be equal to or exceed the one being changed

<sub>On some circuits you may be able to use a higher value of capacitance. However, if the capacitor is used for timing purposes, you can't.</sub>

So, your voltage rating is OK for the replacement but your farad value is too small.

You should also try and match the ESR (effective series resistance) of the replacement to the original and, take note of the maximum operating temperature and "working hours" stated in the data sheets for both parts. Ripple current rating is also important to consider.

<sub>Replacing the capacitor with a type that has a lower ESR may cause instability in some circuits/designs</sub>

All the above assumes that the original design was done properly and that the failure of the original capacitor is not due to bad design. This means that you might get lucky and find that a 2200 μF works perfectly well (when replacing the 4700 μF) but, if it doesn't it might exceed (for example) its ripple current rating and, damage your circuit board beyond repair.

I advocate a decent understanding the original design so you can make an informed choice.